# Запрос на удаления

Tags: mysql

Есть список категорий и у каждой категории есть потомки(они хранится в одной таблице Group(id, name, parent_id) и у каждого потомка есть в другой таблице записи Products(id, id_group, name);

Помогите составить условия.

При удаление выброной категории, если есть потомки удалять всех потомков и из другой таблице в том числе.

Comment: Настраиваете внешний ключ с каскадным удалением. И при удалении одной записи у вас удалятся все зависимые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько я понял вашу структуру, то здесь нужно рекурсивное удаление

```
$db->beginTransaction();

function req_delete($cat_id) use ($db) {
    // удаляем связанные продукты
    $db->execute("DELETE FROM Products WHERE group_id = $cat_id");

    // рекурсивно удаляем детей
    $children = $db->query("SELECT FROM `Group` WHERE parent_id = $cat_id");

    if ($children) {
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            req_delete($children['id']);
        }
    }

    // удаляем категорию
    $db->execute("DELETE FROM `Group` WHERE id = $cat_id");
}

$db->commit();
```

Код на правильность не проверял, так что код только для передачи идеи